# Why set the mass equal to 1 in Hamiltonian for a single particle?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, absolute-units

Why can we set the mass in the Hamiltonian for a single particle equal to 1, as in [Zee p.61](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=n8Mmbjtco78C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false) and Peskin & Schroder p.20? Is it just a choice of units, $\hbar=c=m=1$?

Comment: Yup just a choice of units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, R. Feynman always do this like you. Many textbooks for special Relativity also let $c=1$, so, it is just for Convenience.

Comment: Do you have a ref that Feynman liked setting m=1?

Comment: You can refer to Feynman's lectures.